# Replay recorded plot with new layout in R

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to create and record plots in a 1x1 device:

```
par(mfrow = c(1, 1) )

plot(rnorm(10) )
p1 <- recordPlot()

plot(rnorm(20) )
p2 <- recordPlot()
```

and then to put them in a new layout (e.g., a 1x2 device):

```
par(mfrow = c(1, 2) )

p1
p2
```

However, this produce the same effect (i.e., plotting each plot in a 1x1 device). It seems replaying plots uses the original layout (graphical parameters) that was in effect when they were recorded.

Is there some method that allows a saved plot to be replayed in a new layout ?

NB: I am aware this would be easier via `ggplot2`, but my question is about base plots.

Answer (score 0):

I did some digging, and I don't think this is possible. I used the following to look at what attributes are available inside the object. None of them seemed to indicate the layout could be adjusted.

```
summary(p1)
p1[[1]]
p1[[2]]
```

If you need the same plot across two different layouts could you use set.seed() to recreated the same plot? See the example below.

```
par(mfrow = c(1, 1))
set.seed(1234)
plot(rnorm(10))

par(mfrow = c(1, 2))
set.seed(1234)
plot(rnorm(10))
```

I'd be interested to see if anyone else has a better answer!

Comment: Thank you for digging. This example was actually a simplified version of the situation I'm encountering. I need to store several base plots in a list and to later put them in a new layout. I guess I will have to switch to ggplot2...